# I need to check for data entry through R ...how do I validate that it is in the correct format

Tags: r

Eg : data has to follow the convention xxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

the right data format is 7448-06-93-030-001 or 7448-06-93-030-001-010-030-060

but not 7448-060-030-070.Hope I made some sense

Comment: What is the convention?7448-06-93-030-001 is xxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx but 7448-06-93-030-001-010-030-060 Is xxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "correct format" means the correct number of numeric digits between dashes, here is one solution:

```
test_format <- function(x) {
    #get number of characters of each bunch of digits
    x <- paste0("-", x, "-")
    dash_pos <- unlist(gregexpr("-", x))
    n <- length(dash_pos)
    lens <- dash_pos[2:n] - dash_pos[1:(n-1)] - 1

    #check that this matches the correct convention
    correct_lens <- c(4,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
    isTRUE(all.equal(lens, correct_lens[1:(n-1)]))
}

test_format("7448-06-93-030-001")              #should be true
test_format("7448-06-93-030-001-010-030-060")  #should be true
test_format("7448-060-030-070")                #should be false
```

Comment: Thank you ..Yes ,it is the number of digits ...I am basically trying to vaildate if the data is in the correct format

Comment: can you please walk me through the solution

Comment: I add a dash at the beginning and end of the candidate string, so if you feed in "xxx-xx", I convert it to "-xxx-xx-".  I then use `gregexpr` to find the string positions of the dashes.  So here, the dashes are at positions 1, 5, and 8. `n` tells me how many dashes, including the ones I added at the beginning and end, so here n=3.  `lens` finds the difference between the dash locations, so lens=c(3, 2) because 5-1-1=3 and 8-5-1=2.  After the comment in the middle of the function, I specify what the correct pattern is. Lastly, I see if `lens` matches (all or a part of) the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should work, assuming you want the first pattern of x's

\d{4}-(\d{2}-){2}(\d{3}-){4}\d{3}

https://regular-expressions.mobi/rlanguage.html?wlr=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a blanket `gsub`? These two work for those two scenarios. You could use an `ifelse` to determine which one to use.

```
df <- c("74-486993-030-001")
df <- gsub("-", "", df)
dfa <- gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})$", "\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5", df)

"7448-69-93-030-001"

df2 <- c("74480693-030-00-10-10-030-060")
df2 <- gsub("-", "", df2)
dfb <- gsub("(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})$", "\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5-\\6-\\7-\\8", df2)

"7448-06-93-030-001-010-030-060"
```